# Loading MATLAB .mat files in alphanumerical order

Tags: matlab, sorting, analysis

I'm currently attempting to load a number of MATLAB files which all contain the same variable in order to make a matrix of all the values.

These files all start with a number (i.e. 40_analysed.mat), which was previously extracted from different raw data files using regular expressions, meaning I have a vector composed of all the individual numbers (id).

When I try to load the values and display the data for all individuals in a single matrix using the code below, the files aren't loaded alphanumerically (i.e. according to id), instead appearing to be loaded randomly.

```
file = dir('*_analysed.mat');
for i=1:length(id);
    load(file(i).name,'means');
    overallThresholds{i} = means;
end
overallMeans = cell2mat(overallThresholds)
```

How could I do this so the resulting matrix would be in the correct order? Apologies if this  question doesn't make much sense, the problem is a little hard to articulate!

Comment: Are your numbers in a sensible format? When sorting strings/filenames remember that 07 appears *before* 11 but 7 appears *after* 11.

Comment: What is your OS? There is a solution using Linux and `bash`.

Comment: OSX, so the `bash` solution would is feasible. Is it any simpler than the method below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filenames don't have a fixed-precision number (as @FakeDIY points out, that would mean they would already be sorted), you could do something like this:

```
file = dir('*_analysed.mat');
overalThresholds = cell(1, length(id));
IDs = zeros(1, length(id));
for i = 1:length(id)
    fileName = file(i).name;
    IDs(i)   = str2double( strrep( fileName, '_analysed.mat', '' ) );
    data     = load(fileName, 'means');
    overallThresholds{i} = data.means;
end
[~, reordering] = sort(IDs);
overallThresholds = overallThresholds(reordering);
```

In other words, store the file ID in a separate array as you're going along, and then reorder overallThresholds to be in sorted order of IDs using the second output of [SORT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html).

(I also pre-allocated the arrays, and use the functional form of [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html), but you don't really need to do that).

Comment: This method worked, much appreciated. I'll be sure to use fixed-precision numbers to prevent this issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When one uses `dir` command, it is not promised that the results will be in alphabetical order. In fact, the [manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) says explicitly that:

> dir lists the files and folders in the MATLAB current folder. Results
>   appear in the order returned by the operating system.

Even if you did get this in alphabetical order, nothing assures you that you will get it next time. Thus, you must order the results from `dir` using `sort` command.

```
  [~,order] = sort( {file.name} );
  file = file(order);
```

Comment: Right solution. Just take care that OS can order without taking care of Uppercase - so the order you get is not as the same of your OS. In that case. -> in case http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/lower.html